# Continous cell range in a filtered cells on another sheet or same sheet

Tags: cells, range

I have a data source where I want to assign continuous cell range to the filtered cells only. For example, if I have filtered cell `A1,A40,A79,A118,A157` and so on have a gap of 39 cells/rows and I want to assign continuous cell range from another sheet e.g. `B1,B2,B3,B4,B5` and so on.

But the moment I put `=B1` in the filtered `A1` cell, and further drag it down on the rest of the filtered cells, then instead of taking `B2` in `A40` it's taking as `B40`. Thus I have to manually assign them by typing the cell range, i.e. in `A40` I type `=B2`, in `A79` I type `=B3`, and so on.

Is it possible to assign a formula to the filtered rows so that it takes the continuous cell range?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select cells `A1` through `A352` (or whatever the end of your range is). 
Type

```
=OFFSET(B$1, (ROW()-1)/39, 0)
```

into the formula box and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
(***not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>). 
This will fill each visible cell with that formula. 
This computes the relative row number of the `B` cell
that you want to reference. 
For example:

```
 (1-1)/39 =  0/39 = 0
(40-1)/39 = 39/39 = 1
(79-1)/39 = 78/39 = 2
```

etc. 
The `OFFSET` function then counts down that many rows from cell `B$1`,
so `A1` references `B1`, `A40` references `B2`, `A79` references `B3`, etc.

Comment: It works Perfect.. Thank you very much.. I struggled for this alot.. you made my life easy.. Thank you once again Scott..  you rock!!! :D